# Using $_POST and $_SESSION - passing variables between pages

Tags: php, session

I have an index page which gets passed `$_POST['timestart']` and `$_POST['timeend']` variables.  In addition, I have a cart page that has variables passed to it from the index page, and it passes variables back (with `header`) to the index page depending on what is done.  In order to retain the initial `$_POST['timestart']` and `$_POST['timeend']` variables, I end up storing these variables in a SESSION.  My final solution, which works, is something like this.

My index page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_POST != NULL)
{
    $_SESSION['date'] = $_POST;
    $timestart = new \DateTime($_SESSION['date']['timestart']);
    $timeend = new \DateTime($_SESSION['date']['timeend']);
    $start = $timestart->format('Y-m-d');
    $end = $timeend->format('Y-m-d');
} 
elseif ($_POST == NULL && $_SESSION != NULL)
{
    $timestart = new \DateTime($_SESSION['date']['timestart']);
    $timeend = new \DateTime($_SESSION['date']['timeend']);
    $start = $timestart->format('Y-m-d');
    $end = $timeend->format('Y-m-d');
}
elseif ($_POST == NULL && $_SESSION == NULL)
{
    $start = "";
    $end = "";
}

if ($start == NULL && $end == NULL)
{
    echo 'please select a date range';
}
else
{
....main page....
    <form method="post" action="cart/cart_update.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="model_name" value="<?php echo $item ?>" />
    <input  type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $current_url ?>" />
    </form>
}
```

My cart page (just so it is clear what is happening):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET["emptycart"]) && $_GET["emptycart"]==1)
{
    $return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]);
    unset($_SESSION["inventory"]);
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add')
{
    $model_name = filter_var($_POST["model_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $qty = filter_var($_POST["qty"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $return_url = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]);
    $new_item = array(array('name'=>$model_name, 'qty'=>$qty));
    $start = $_POST["timestart"];
    $end = $_POST["timeend"];
    if(isset($_SESSION["inventory"]))
    {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($_SESSION["inventory"] as $cart_itm)
        {
            if ($cart_itm["name"] == $model_name)
            {
                $model[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'qty'=>$qty);
                $found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                $model[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"]);
            }
        }
        if($found == false)
        {
            $_SESSION["inventory"] = array_merge($model, $new_item);
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION["inventory"] = $model;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["inventory"] = $new_item;
    }
header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
if(isset($_GET["removep"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["inventory"]))
{
    $model_name = $_GET["removep"];
    $return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]);
    $model = NULL;
    foreach ($_SESSION["inventory"] as $cart_itm)
    {
        if($cart_itm["name"]!=$model_name)
        {
            $model[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"]);
        }
        $_SESSION["inventory"] = $model;
    }
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
?>
```

**My question**...for the code I am using in the index page:

```
if ($_POST != NULL)
{
    $_SESSION['date'] = $_POST;
    $timestart = new \DateTime($_SESSION['date']['timestart']);
    $timeend = new \DateTime($_SESSION['date']['timeend']);
    $start = $timestart->format('Y-m-d');
    $end = $timeend->format('Y-m-d');
} 
elseif ($_POST == NULL && $_SESSION != NULL)
{
    $timestart = new \DateTime($_SESSION['date']['timestart']);
    $timeend = new \DateTime($_SESSION['date']['timeend']);
    $start = $timestart->format('Y-m-d');
    $end = $timeend->format('Y-m-d');
}
elseif ($_POST == NULL && $_SESSION == NULL)
{
    $start = "";
    $end = "";
}
```

Is this idea a good solution, or is there a better, more elegant way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is that using $_POST == NULL and $_SESSION == NULL is too general and could lead to errors. You should use specific conditions for $_POST["date"] and also validate the data. Plus, I would avoid the repetition in your code by calling a function.

```
// will return NULL if $dt not valid or empty
function get_valid_date($dt) {
    if (!empty($dt)) {
        try {
            $temp=new \DateTime($dt);
            return $temp->format("Y-m-d");
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

// temp store for either $_POST["date"] or $_SESSION["date"] if isset
$date=array();

if (isset($_POST["date"])) {
    $date=$_POST["date"];
} else if (isset($_SESSION["date"])) {
    $date=$_SESSION["date"];
}

// get valid $start/$end date from $date - NULL if not valid or empty
$start = get_valid_date($date["timestart"]);
$end = get_valid_date($date["timeend"]);

// save $date in $_SESSION only if both $start and $end are valid
if (!empty($start) && !empty($end)) {
    $_SESSION["date"]=$date;
} else {
    unset($_SESSION["date"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will be more specific to rule out potential issues as you suggest.  Is there anything against using `if (isset($_POST['date']) == "true")` vs using `!empty`?  Are there any differences between the two?

Comment: This post has a nice table to explain the difference between isset, empty, and is_null: https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/ Each has it's own use. The biggest difference: if a value is "" (empty string), the isset() will return TRUE, but the !empty() will return FALSE. So, you could also use (!empty($_POST["date"])) to make sure that you exclude cases like: "", 0, "0", FALSE, NULL  (but this gets tested in the function) Cheers!